# Purpose built light-weight alternative to SSL/TLS?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

Target hardware is a rather low-powered MCU (ARM Cortex-M3 @72MHz, with just about 64KB SRAM and 256KB flash), so walking the thin line here. My board does have ethernet, and I will eventually get lwIP (lightweight TCP/IP FOSS suite) running on it (currently struggling). However, I also need some kind of super light-weight alternative to SSL/TLS. I am aware of the multiple GPL'd SSL/TLS implementations for such MCU's, but their footprint is still fairly significant. While they do fit-in, given everything else, don't leave much room for others.

My traffic is not HTTP, so I don't have to worry about HTTPS, and my client/server communication can be completely proprietary, so non-standard solution is okay. Looking for suggestions on what might be the minimalistic yet robust (well a weak security is worthless), alternative that helps me --

1. Encrypt my communication (C->S & S->C)
2. Do 2-way authentication (C->S & S->C)
3. Avoid man-in-middle attacks

I won't be able to optimize library at ARMv7 assembly level, and thus bank entirely on my programming skills and the GNU-ARM compiler's optimization. Given above, any pointers of what might be the best options ?

Comment: You might want to consider asking this question on http://security.stackexchange.com/ too.

Comment: thanks @bavarious. Will definitely take your advice and post there as well.

Comment: @bavarious. your suggestion really paid off. got some excellent answers there as well, in addition to the ones here. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/compuationally-simple-lightweight-replacement-for-ssl-tls

Comment: Great. There’s also an Area 51 suggestion for a cryptography-focused Stack Exchange site but it hasn’t gathered many committed users yet, so for the moment security.SE seems to be the best place for these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any of those small TLS implementations allow you to disable all X.509 and ASN.1 functionality and just use TLS with preshared-keys you'd have quite a small footprint. That's because only symmetric ciphers and hashes are used.

Comment: Thanks @Nikos, that sounds like an excellent thing to try. Dropping all pretense of knowing a lot about security/cryptography, may I ask, as they this mechanism is not used by-and-large ? Are there some inherent weaknesses / shortcomings / challenges to using preshared-keys, and using symmertric ciphers / hashes ? Anyhow, I've got a great lead, and will certainly research this further.

Comment: @mike they have no shortcomings that I know of and they are an [IETF proposed standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279). What you should be aware however is that the "performance" TLS cipher-suites such as the plain PSK ones and the RSA ones that do not involve Diffie-Hellman key exchange, do not offer perfect forward secrecy. In simpler words, if someone steals the key he can decrypt all past sessions.

Answer (score 5):

There's [CurveCP](http://curvecp.org/). It's meant to completely replace SSL.

It's fairly new, and still undergoing development, but its author is a well-known expert in the field, and has been carefully working toward it during the past decade.  A *lot* of careful research and design has been put into it.

Answer (score 2):

My immediate reaction would be to consider [Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/). It's been heavily studied, so the chances of major holes at this point are fairly remote. At the same time, it's fairly minimalist, so unless you restrict *what* you need to do, you're probably not going to be able to use anything much more lightweight without compromising security.

If that's still too heavy for your purposes, you're *probably* going to need to impose some restrictions on what you want done.

Comment: @jerry-coffin, thanks for the alternative. Read the Kerberos wikipedia page and also the MIT link. This looks like a viable possibility, although I'm yet to find an implementation for Cortex-M3's. Will definitely follow this lead. My client-server communication is based on a simple TCP based binary protocol.

Comment: Kerberos is not encryption/decryption stack, it serves for different very complex (and memory- & CPU-hungry purposes), hence it won't fir for this task

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at MST (Minimal Secure Transport) https://github.com/DiplIngFrankGerlach/MST.

It provides the same security assurances as TLS, but requires a pre-shared key. Also, it is very small (less than 1000 LoC, without AES) and can therefore easily be reviewed by an expert.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is to come with variant of answer about two years later, yet... "PolarSSL's memory footprint can get as small as 30k and averages below 110k." https://polarssl.org/features